# Upgrade Kubuntu to 22.04 LTS leads to NM go crazy

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, network-manager, 22.04

I've updated my system from 21.10 to 22.04 and NetworkManager go crazy. 32% cpu usage. Plasma crashes(I believe because of this). But Logs I can see it constantly reconnects to wifi also. How to fix it? Did anyone experience such behavior? Wifi worked perfectly on the previous ubuntu version.

Comment: You should try a Kubuntu 22.04 live session and compare. If the problem is the same then something about the version being shipped now needs to be corrected. OTOH, if it works as expected then it's something that went wrong with the release upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Reason was miredo package. After remove it everything works!

`$ sudo apt remove miredo`